# Accessing data through method ,in which is defined Static, php code not giving any output

Tags: php

Accessing data through method which is Static,but its not showing the result

```
<?php
class Dog{

    static $noseColor = 1 ;

    function ShowAll(){

        Dog::$noseColor = 10;
    }

}

$pitbull = new Dog();
Dog::ShowAll();
?>
```

result should be just 10 , but the actual output is nothing !

Comment: You're not creating any output, just assigning values.

Comment: There is no `echo`, `print_r` or whatever...

Comment: You are not printing anything. Please try with `echo`, `print_r`, `error_log`, `var_dump` or something

Answer (score 1):

The comments below your question are absolutely right, but there is more to consider with your class **as it stands**:

- once you defined `$pitbull`, your next line should be `$pitbull->ShowAll()`. The way you have it is for calling static methods but your `ShowAll()` method is not static.
- even with the above change, you still need to do something like: `echo $pitbull->ShowAll()`, `print_r($pitbull->ShowAll())`, `var_dump($pitbull->ShowAll())`

A couple of other suggestions:

- You have a static `$noseColor` property. You can also get that without first instantiating the class. For example: `echo Dog::$noseColor`
- The `ShowAll()` is defaulted to "public", but it's good practice to declare it as `public function ShowAll()`, unless you want it protected or private.
- A constructor would be helpful too:

```php
class Dog{

    static $noseColor = 1 ;
    //non-static property
    public $dogNoseColor;

    // you can set a default to the constructor too
    public function __construct(int $noseColor = 1) {

        $this->dogNoseColor = $noseColor;
        //or
        self::$noseColor = $noseColor;
    }

    // this has access to static and non-static properties;
    public function ShowAll(){

       return $this->dogNoseColor;
       //or
        return self::$noseColor;

    }
    // this does not immediately have access to non-static properties but can be called without instantiation
    public static function ShowAllStatic(int $newNoseColor)
    {
        return self::$noseColor = $newNoseColor;
        // you can also do this
        $pitbull = new self(10);
        return $pitbull->ShowAll();

    }

}
```

Hope this helps
edit: the above example has two `returns` for each method, which is wrong. It's just to indicate that you could choose either one of those returns;